# How to continuously check current window height of web page?

Tags: css, height

I have a navbar on a website and after reaching a certain point of the height(y axis). I'd like to manipulate the css Code of my navbar for example the background color.

So far so good now I check with an if statement the height and if it overcomes a certain value I manipulate the css of the navbar class....but how can i make sure this gets checked constantly i have used the setInterval method but im not sure if this is a good solution...anyone who can help me out?

Thanks in advance!

```
function update() {
  if (currentHeight>600) {
    $(".class").css({"background-color":"blue"});
  } else {
    $(".class").css({"background-color":"transparent"}); 
  }
}

setInterval(update, 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with jQuery like this:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    if ($(window).height()>600) {
    $(".class").css({"background-color":"blue"});
    } else {
    $(".class").css({"background-color":"transparent"}); 
   }
});
```

You can also do it without jquery with using CSS `@media` tags:

```
.class {
    background-color:blue;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 600px) {
  .class {
    background-color:transparent;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change CSS when your screen is too small, you might not need jQuery:

```
@media screen and (max-height: 600px) {
  .class {background-color:transparent}
}
```